# Float divs goes under each other when scaling down the window size

Tags: html, css

I want to do a simple webpage, where there are 3 divs, one vertical on the left side of the screen and two on it's right, so that when i scale down the windows width, the vertical one get thinner until it reach it's min-width, and so the two horizontal ones. And only when they both reach the min-width, if you keep scaling down the windows size, the two horizontal ones goes under the vertical, one under the other.

The problem is: when i scale down the windows size, all divs get thinner, but once the vertical div reach him min-width, the two horizontal ones goes under it.

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#wra{
    margin: auto;
    width: 99%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#ver{
    width: 30%;
    height: 700px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    float: left;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#or1{
  width: 69%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wra">
    <div id="ver"><p>Vertical Div</p></div>
    <div id="or1"><p>Orizontal Div 1</p></div>
    <div id="or1"><p>Orizontal Div 2</p></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks for the help

Comment: You need to look into media queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is a result of the vertical element (`#ver`) is no longer occupying `30%` of the available space when its `min-width` declaration is fulfilled (it is occupying more), so the horizontal elements (`#or1`) no longer have `69%` of the available space left to occupy; forcing them to collapse below the vertical element.

#### Solutions:

**@Media Queries**

Declaring `@media` queries at specified breakpoints (e.g: `@media(max-width: 768px) {...}`) would be the standard solution to a typical responsive issue such as this one.

- [Creating Media Queries for Responsive Web Designs](https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-media-queries-for-responsive-web-designs/) - SitePoint
- [How To Use CSS3 Media Queries To Create a Mobile Version of Your
  Website](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) - Smashing Magazine

**Flex-Box**

`flex-box` is a popular solution to typical responsive issues since it leverages built-in browser processing to calculate elements widths and available space for precision alignment - it does all the "heavy lifting" so you don't have to (most of the time anyway).

It's a fairly new technology, so support for legacy browsers (like IE11 and below) are limited or non-existent. If this is going to be a concern for you, then I would advise adding fallback styles for "graceful degradation", or to avoid using `flex-box` entirely. *see links included below embedded code snippet for browser support and compatibility*

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

*Note:*

1. An additional class has been added (`.horizontal-resize`) to allow user-friendly horizontal resizing - this is intended
   for demonstration and should be removed before committing to
   production.
2. `.class` selectors have been used in favour of `#id` selectors - this is
   generally considered better practice as `id` attributes should remain unique, and
   non-repeating. It also bears significantly more **weight** than
   typical *class* selectors and will always *over-qualify* class
   selectors as a result (even if those class selectors appear to carry
   more *specificity*) - this may cause issues down the line for you when attempting to declare style rules.
3. An additional containing element has been inserted to wrap the
   horizontal elements, this is required for the `flex-box` styles
   (declared on the containing parent element `.wra`) to function as
   intended - since `flex-box` has a "parent-to-direct-descendant"
   relationship (`flex-box` rules will not apply to elements that are
   nested more than 2 levels deep from a containing element with the
   `display: flex` declared).

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.wra {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* 
   allows you to resize the containing wrapper element 
   intended for the sake of demonstration only - remove for production 
*/
.horizontal-resize {
  resize: horizontal; 
}

.ver {
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  flex: 1 1 300px;
  max-width: 30%;
}

.or1 {
  flex: 1 1 300px;
  max-width: 70%;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.or1-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 20px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wra horizontal-resize">
    <div class="ver"><p>Vertical Div</p></div>
    <div class="or1">
      <div class="or1-inner"><p>Orizontal Div 1</p></div>
      <div class="or1-inner"><p>Orizontal Div 2</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Cross Browser Compatibility & Support:**

- [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex)
- [Using CSS Flexible Boxes - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score -1):

This is because of z-index. Please learn it first and then apply. It will be clear to you then. `The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element`.